# SWRevealViewController back to previous viewcontroller not working

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using SWRevealViewController and I'm trying to implement a back button

there's my code to go to another view:

```
- (IBAction)goViewController:(id)sender {
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"globalFIndAutoCompleteID"];
[self.revealViewController pushFrontViewController:topViewController animated:YES];
}
```

and my backbutton code:

```
  - (IBAction)backClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    [self.revealViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem replacing the code with the following:

```
-(void) goViewController:(UIButton *)sender{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
appDelegate.previousController = self;

   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"globalFIndAutoCompleteID"];
  [self.revealViewController presentViewController:topViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (IBAction)backClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```