# SWRevealViewController button not work after clicking Back button from another ViewController in Swift

Tags: swift3, back-button, swrevealviewcontroller

I use SWRevealViewController for my project. 
My problem is that I can click on the **SWRevealView Toggle button** at first time and that button *does not work* after I click on Back button from another view controller and back to that view. 
Here is the screenshot of my project. 
[image]

I click on NavigationLeft button from Service View Controller at first and left menu shows up. 
 After that, I click on "Imageview" from that view controller to go to next page. 
When I reached to detailed next page, I click on "Back button" and it goes to Service view controller. 
 
At that time , I click on RevealView Toggle button , it does not work. I got error **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**.

My codes from **Service View Controllers** are;

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        debugPrint("Menu Click")
        btnBack.target = self.revealViewController()
        btnBack.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer()

    }

    else
    {
        debugPrint("nil")
        btnBack.target = self.revealViewController()
        btnBack.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        // self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer()

    }


}
```

When the project runs first time, the code passes to "self.revealViewController() != nil" and I go to detailed view controller and click on Back button. At that time the code passes to " debugPrint("nil")" and it does not show up menu or work. 
**Codes from Detailed view controller** are;

```
 @IBAction func btnBack(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    debugPrint("BtnBack")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)

}
```

Is my code is something wrong or logic wrong ? I have been trying to solve this problem since one week. Please help me ..

Comment: please post also your menu initialization code.

Comment: I use SWReavealController library. Here is the link bro https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/.  I declared menu code in viewDIdLoad.

Comment: I think this is wrong. you will have to menu initialization code in your AppDelegate file to solve your problem. check this link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363570/swrevealviewcontroller-back-to-previous-viewcontroller-not-working

Comment: have you got a solution or not?

Comment: still solving bro @HardikShekhat

Comment: can you attach your complete project

Comment: attach ur project I will checl

Comment: bro @Anbu.Karthik, I edit my screenshot image and code bro.  
my project size is over 1.5GB bro. I could not attach.

Answer (score 1):

On click event of image view in serviceViewController,

```
let detailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as! DetailVc
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
```

Attach a navigation controller to detail viewcontroller. No need for manual connection between service and detail.
Add a barbutton for goingback event.

```
 self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Also add `self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())` instead of ur code in the lastline of adding target for menubutton.

Check whether this works.